SSIS Remove quotation from insert script to ADO NET Destination
I had try to insert data to Cloudera/Hive using SSIS.Connection I used from SSIS to Cloudera using ODBC.
I got an issue when execute the task, the script generated for insert including double quotation at the column name. How to remove that from the script generated? You can see the query here

This is what my data flow looks like

The error is

[ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [42000] [Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:25 cannot recognize input near '"idbank"' ',' '"idnamapengurus"' in statement
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Any idea to remove the quotation from the insert script generated by SSIS? or configure the Hive to read the quotation?
Thanks

If you are getting the error on the flat file source, the file probably has quotes as text qualifiers.  In the Flat File Source there is option to say the file is text qualified.  find that and check it and it should remove the quotes on import.

At connection manager I don't configure to use text qualifier and the source file don't have a text qualifier. I think the double quotes generate automatically when generate the INSERT script and I don't know why the values not generated, only the question mark.
this is the script generated by SSIS and executing on Hive
https://i.sstatic.net/77Bh2.png
this is the configuration and content from the flat file source
https://i.sstatic.net/kMrCj.png

Please provide logged text inline. Posting links to screenshots hosted on third party sites is prone to break, and not easily accessible for those with impaired vision.

See the below Flat File Connection Manager.
Your file is probably Text Qualified and you need to add Text Qualifier of Double Quotes to this editor screen.

